# CSS relative after absolute positioning

Tags: css, css-position

How to place element to the right side, and keep persistent position of following elements?

I want to align `<p class="t2">Efficiently ...</p>` to the right side without `text-align: right` and keep the space between `t2` and `t3` element.

When I use `position: absolute` I can move it to the right using `right: 0` but the next element with class `t3` is moved up, omitting `t2` margins, paddings etc. I can move it down adding `margin-down` to the `wrap` but I can't do this precisely (keeping the specific distance between `t2` and `t3`).

I know differences between *relative*, *absolute* etc. Currently I'm looking a better way to keep the same effect using alternative methods.

```css
.hero {
  background: #00aaff;
  padding-top: 32px;
  padding-bottom: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}
.hero .wrap {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-width: 320px;
  max-width: 50%;
}
.wrap .t2 {
  margin-top: 1.625em;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
.hero .t3 {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.t3 .slogan, .t3 .phone {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<section class="hero">
  <div class="wrap">  <!-- wrapping t1, t2 -->
    <p class="t1">Lorem ipsum empowered <br>networks.</p>         <!-- align left -->
    <p class="t2">Efficiently unleash cross-media <br>ipsum.</p>  <!-- align right -->
  </div>
  <p class="t3">
    <span class="slogan">Contact with us.</span>
    <span class="phone">Call 123 456 789</span>
  </p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Bootstrap Grid system. http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_examples.asp

Comment: I don't want to use bootstrap. It should be the way to improve my code to achieve the same effect and keep the website arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

It was so easy... I just used `float: right` with `position: relative` and there is no problem with the wrong placement of objects.